# codeigniter ignores empty post data..issue with validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can i show the empty field that user submit??

```
if($this->input->post('name')){
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
}elseif(!empty($details)) {
    $data['name'] = $details['name'];
}else{
    $data['name'] = '';
}
```

But if user **clear the input field** and submit, it wont show the **input as empty** it will execute the **elseif statement** though user submit post request.

How to avoid this?

**i want to say the field is empty**

Comment: cant you use jquery to validate?

Comment: please check possibly the duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829722/codeigniter-validate-empty-value

Comment: it is not @Sudarshan

Comment: but try out the solution, cant you use javascript or jquery to validate?

Comment: try isset($this->input->post('name')) or  !empty($this->input->post('name'))

Comment: why $details is post data ?

Answer (score 1):

$this->input->post returns false only when name is absent in POST array

```
$data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
// here empty($data['name']) gives you correct answer
if (!$data['name'])
   $data['name'] = empty($details) ? '' : $details['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This validation checks whether the field in the $_POST exists or not.

If you want to restrict the user to avoid empty entries.
There 2 approaches for that:

1) Client side (use jquery or javascript or just use html5's tag `required='required'` in `<input` tag that would work)

2) Server side,

```
if($this->input->post('name')){
   $setErrorMessage = "Empty field is not allowed";  
}
```

and return the user to the page along with the error message(s).